# ProgressBar и RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-asynctask, progress-bar, recyclerview.adapter

В `MainActivity` лежит фрагмент в `FrameLayout`. В этом фрагменте лежит `RecyclerView`. Как только я перехожу во фрагмент, у меня через `AsyncTask` подгружаются картинки из интернета в мой список. Соответственно это занимает кое-какое время.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно организовать работу, чтобы при переходе во фрагмент логика была примерно такая: отображается `ProgressBar` и одновременно с этим идет загрузка картинок, как только загрузка завершается - адаптер обновляется, `ProgressBar` исчезает, а вместо него появляется `RecyclerView` с загруженными картинками.

Comment: `setVisible(..)`?

Comment: @post_zeew так это подошло бы если бы я работал в активити. 
`progressbar - visible`    
`recyclerview - invisible`       
`Загрузка картинок, обновление адаптера`         
`progressbarr - gone`        
`recyclerview - visible`           

А как делать во фрагменте, в котором метод `onCreateView(...)` возвращает view?

Comment: Точно так же, как и в активити. Какие именно у Вас возникли проблемы?

Comment: @post_zeew я конечно попробую, но это ведь не логично. Не понимаю.

Comment: @post_zeew т.е. мне изначально в хмл лайауте ставить видимым прогресс бар, невидимым ресайклвью. потом делаю все нужные мне дела в методе `onCreateView()`, затем меняю настройки видимости прогрессбара и ресайклвью. и в конце концов: `return view` ? Так должно сработать? Смогу проверить только завтра с утра, отпишусь сразу.

Comment: Ну примерно так, да.

Comment: @YaPV на вашем месте я бы рассмотрел вариант: `RecyclerView` сразу отображает содержимое адаптера (загруженная картинка или placeholder на время загрузки из сети). Самая простая реализация этого - через `Picasso`